# PostgresSQL ranking across two tables with same columns

Tags: postgresql

I have two tables, studentrecordupdated and studentrecordlegacy, with student record legacy being in the legacy schema.

Both the forms have the same data, only difference being that the studentrecordlegacy table has record forms which are not in the studentrecordupdated table. I am joining these two tables on studentid.

How do I don't a rank over partition by using both tables (some of the records in the legacy table are more recent than in the updated table)?

Comment: What do you mean by *"How do I don't a rank over partition"*?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some [sample data](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Comment: I think you're only shot is to perform a UNION of the two tables and then apply your ranking on the same column.